# For given set of ids, check in db exists and which not, return both as separate list spring data jpa

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I am working on Spring data JPA,

I have a requirement where I have list of ids present with me.They are approx `12-15k` ids.

I want to query database to find if given id exists:

**This query should return two lists:**

1. List of ids that are present in db
2. List of ids that are not present in db.

Also want to leverage IN clause as it will help me to query 1K records in single go.

I want to write db agnostic implementation so looking for jpql/hql query.

**What I know so far is:**

1. Ill have to split 15k ids in batch of 1000
2. Then I can pass these ids as set of ids to query, with in query)
   eg:

   `IdsQueryResult  result = repository.findByIdsIn(Set<Long> ids);`
3. This can return a [interface projection](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections.interfaces)

```java
interface IdsQueryResult {
     Set<Long> getIdsFound();
     Set<Long> getIdsNotFound();
}
```

Any help appreciated

Comment: Instead of repository.find* you can use repository.existsByIdIn without actually loading the entity.